# F# keyword is a field in Firebase JSON - workaround?

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, f#, json.net, record

I have the following record defined in `F#`:

```
type ListingContent = 
{ from : string
  landlord_id : string
  listing_id : string
  location : string
  name : string
  pic_1_url : string
  pic_2_url : string
  pic_3_url : string
  pic_4_url : string
  pic_5_url : string
  messages : Map<string, Map<string,MessageContent>> 
  postcode : string
  price_per_night : string
  to_date : string;
}
```

I am using the following code:

```
let listings_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types.ListingContent>(html)
```

to parse the following JSON:

```
    {  
   "from":"19/01/2018",
   "landlord_id":"YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
   "listing_id":"-L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB",
   "location":"Edinburgh",
   "name":"dan",
   "pic_1_url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....",
   "pic_2_url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....",
   "pic_3_url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....",
   "pic_4_url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....",
   "pic_5_url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....",
   "postcode":"....",
   "price_per_night":"£32",
   "to":"19/01/2019"
}
```

This parses everything fine except the `to` field, because I am using `to_date` in my record, it parses to `null`... `to` is a keyword in `F#` therefore I cannot use it in my record definition. I can't really change the JSON in the database at this point. Is there any workaround around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a keyword as identifier by enclosing it in double backticks:

```
``to``: string
```

The backticks themselves will not become part of the identifier, only what's inside of them. This way, the JSON library will see a field named "to" and you will be able to refer to it from F# as ``` listingContent.``to`` ```

This trick also works for identifiers with spaces and other non-identifier characters:

```
let ``some identifier`` = 42
let ``007`` = "Bond"
```

Alternatively, you can tell JSON.NET itself to use a different name for the property via the [`JsonProperty` attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor_1.htm):

```
[<JsonProperty "to">] to_date : string
```

Comment: Thanks guys, you both posted the same thing so I'll upvote both and accept the first answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the name with backticks:

```
``to`` : string
```